# Can I use an LC-SC fiber optic cable with a 10G NIC that only mentions support for LC-LC cables?

Tags: networking, fiber

Specs (ftp://ftp.supermicro.com/CDR-NIC_1.32_for_Add-on_NIC_Cards/MANUALS/datasheet-AOC-STGN-i2S.pdf) for Supermicro Fiber NIC AOC-STGN-i2S say it supports LC-LC 10G cables.  Is there any reason to think LC-SC would not work?

I want to connect this NIC with a Cisco WS-C3560E-12D 10G switch which only has X2 slots, and as far as I can tell, there are no converters or adapters that will allow me to plug in a SR module (with an LC connector) to this switch.  Hence, I am trying to find out if the NIC card will care if I try using an LC-SC cable instead.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading, but I think it says it supports DUAL LC cables (as in 2) not that they have to be LC terminated at both ends..

Comment: You are so right! ! I can't believe I misunderstood that! It's a two-port card, so duh :)

Answer (score 0):

I used to run a SAN that did LC-SC because we had a 'standard' that was SC patch panels (because of the networking). It works fine - they are, after all, only optic fibers with connectors on the end. (Although we did need to split the connectors because of a double crossover effect).

The thing you have to watch is the fiber diameter - common sizes are 50 micron and 62.5 micron. It's not a particularly good plan to mismatch, because you'll get more attenuation and potentially other problems.

Answer (score 0):

The switch module won't know what connectors are in use. It is purely mechanical fact.

I do have this exact configuration myself. No problems.